# How to accept a public static variable as parameter in Java

Tags: java

I have the following instantiated variable

```
 public static int r1 = 10;
```

I have several of these variables `r1` - `r4`, I want to write a method that will be able to take the variable `r1` as a parameter of the method and increment it.

Pseudo code would look like :

```
r1 = r1 + 1;
```

My question is how can I take the variable as a parameter of one method instead of writing 4 different methods to accomplish this?

Comment: `instead of writing 4 different methods to accomplish this` ... where did four methods come into the question?

Comment: Why not simply use `YourClassName.r1` inside method ? You don't need a parameter to pass on `public static` variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, because Java does not let you pass variables of primitive types by reference.

You can put your variables into an array, and pass an array and an index:

```
public static int[] r = new int[4];
...
public static void modify(int[] array, int pos) {
    array[pos]++;
}
...
modify(MyClass.r, 1); // instead of modify(MyClass.r1);
```

Alternative approach is to return the modified value to callers, and let them assign it back:

```
public static int modify(int orig) {
    return orig+1;
}
...
MyClass.r1 = modify(MyClass.r1);
```